# I don't understand why my custom validations (Blazor) are displaying twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, blazor

I have created several custom validations that require a secondary field to become mandatory if associated check box is checked. All that was working fine.

Recently, the client asked if we can 'hide' the secondary field and only display it if the associated check box is checked. Since I added that code all of my validation errors are displaying twice.

Example:

Page

```html
<RadzenLabel Text="Other:  " />&nbsp;&nbsp; <RadzenCheckBox @bind-Value=@WIR40Entity.type_other  Name="CheckBox15" @onclick="@HideOtherP"  />

<RadzenLabel Text="If Other, Please Describe:  " hidden="@HideOther" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<RadzenTextBox hidden="@HideOther" @bind-Value=@WIR40Entity.OtherIncidentType onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" MaxLength="100" class="w-100" />
```

Code

```cs
private bool HideOther { get; set; } = true;

public void HideOtherP()
{
    HideOther = !HideOther;
}
```

Model

```cs
[CustomCompareAttributesOther(nameof(OtherIncidentType))]
public bool? type_other { get; set; }
```

Custom Attribute

```cs
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        int count2 = 0;
        WIR40 entity = (WIR40)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        if (entity.type_other == true && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.OtherIncidentType))
        {
            {
                return new ValidationResult("When selecting Other as an Incident Action: A Description is also required.");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I have placed a STOP in the Validation Result, and then step through line by line. It hits the line:

```cs
return new ValidationResult("When selecting Other . . . . . .");
```

And then it jumps to the `return ValidationResult.Success;` and then it jumps back up to the first line again. Causing the Validation error to post twice.

I am not understanding why this happens and why it did not happen when I was not hiding/unhiding the components.

Any insight to help me better understand why this is happening and how to resolve it, would be appreciated.